# Receive html source from the web page using Robot Framework

Tags: python, html, robotframework

I try to get html source of the web-page using Robot Framework. But I don't want to use Selenium2Library because it starts a web-browser and takes a lot of time.

Can you recommend me any Robot Framework libraries? I can write my own Library on Python using urllib2 etc. but I think there is more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [requests library](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/#readme), which uses the requests python library to fetch resources on the web.

```
*** Settings ***
| Library     | RequestsLibrary
| Suite Setup | Create Session | example | http://www.example.com

*** Test Cases ***
| Example using the requests library
| | ${response}= | Get | example | /
| | log | ${response.content}
```

Comment: The above library posted by Bryan will do the job but if you need a bit more than making request / receiving response, have a look at https://github.com/peritus/robotframework-httplibrary/. I've been using this library in several projects and can recommend it.